# What does `x` refer to in this Oracle SQL statement: `select * from dual where x=1 or 1=1`

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I accidentally found that in Oracle SQL one can issue the following statement:
`select * from dual where x=1 or 1=1`.

1. The column in `dual` is named `dummy` and not `x`.
2. If I select from any other table, it still works, returning all rows.
3. `select * from dual where y=1 or 1=1` also works.
4. `select * from dual where z=1 or 1=1` *does not work*, giving `ORA-00904: z: invalid identifier`.
5. `select * from dual where x=1` *does not work*, giving `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_X'`.

What do `x` and `y` refer to?

Comment: I am getting error while using x and y also. what is the tool you are using to execute these statements? I am using sql developer.

Comment: @ShravanYadav I'm using PL/SQL Developer, but I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have tried all the sql in sqldeveloper and toad. not working for me. getting same error in all 3. ORA-00904

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to happen because on some Oracle DB versions there exist *synonyms* named X and Y:

```
select owner, synonym_name, table_owner, table_name from dba_synonyms where synonym_name in ('X', 'Y');

OWNER                          SYNONYM_NAME                   TABLE_OWNER                    TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
PUBLIC                         X                              MDSYS                          OGC_X
PUBLIC                         Y                              MDSYS                          OGC_Y
```

Comment: I think these public synonyms are left-over from 10g or earlier, based on the `DBA_OBJECTS.CREATED` column from some of my databases.  I'm glad Oracle stopped doing this, this looks very confusing!